# How to get checkbox value in Oracle Apex application

Tags: oracle, checkbox, plsql, oracle-apex

I created the following pl/sql code in order to obtain the value of the checked row.

```
BEGIN
FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
 UPDATE TEST_CHECK_STATUS 
 SET check_status = 1
 WHERE rowid = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(I));
END LOOP;
END;
```

When execute this code i obtain this error:

> ORA-06550: line 6, column 16: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date    pipe

someone tell me where is the error?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your PL/SQL, but the error message refers to "line 6, column 16" - but there is no "BEGIN" at that location. Therefore, one can only speculate that this is part of a larger PL/SQL program, and that some code appearing before this point is incorrect. Alternatively, apex is not treating this code as PL/SQL and is attempting to run it as a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, there is no syntax error in your statement. Did you really save your code block as PL/SQL anonymous block (not a block returning a boolean value and not a SQL block (!))?